# Physical Chemistry: Specifically the Dissolution of Carbonates

Tags: physical-chemistry, equilibrium, aqueous-solution, concentration, geochemistry

Please note this question is different to the other that keeps being mentioned. That one is about the concentration of just  $\ce{HCO3-}$ when no $\ce {pH}$ was given.
Whereas, in this one I am trying to find the concentrations of $\ce{H+}$, $\ce{HCO3-}$, $\ce{CO3^{2-}}$, and $\ce{Ca^2+}$, with a given $\ce {pH}$.

Consider the following equations:

\begin{align}
\ce{CO2(g) + H2O(l) &<=> H2CO3(aq)} &\quad K_{\ce{CO2}} &= 10^{-1.47} \tag{1}\\
\ce{H2CO3(aq) &<=> H+(aq) + HCO3-(aq)} &\quad K_1 &= 10^{-6.35} \tag{2}\\
\ce{HCO3-(aq) &<=> H+(aq) + CO3^{2-}(aq)} &\quad K_2 &= 10^{-10.33} \tag{3}\\
\ce{CaCO3(s) &<=> Ca^{2+}(aq) + CO3^{2-}(aq)} &\quad K_{\text{cal}} &= 10^{-8.48} \tag{4}\\
\end{align}

Atmospheric $\ce{CO2}$ is at $\pu{10^{-3.5} atm}$ and the solution is pure water.
Also, in equation $(4)$ calcite crystals are added in excess ($\ce{CaCO3}$).

So far I have been able to find the equilibrium equations and have got the concentration of $\ce{H2CO3}$ to be $10^{-4.97}$ by multiplying the atmospheric $\ce{CO2}$ by the value of $K_{\ce{CO2}}$.

Having been told the $\mathrm{pH}$ of the solution is 8.26, I then calculated the concentration of $\ce{H+}$ to be $10^{-8.26}$.

Using my values of $\ce{H2CO3}$ and $\ce{H+}$ and substituting them into the equilibrium equation for (2),I have the concentration of $\ce{HCO3-}$ to be $10^{-3.06}$. Is this correct?

Continuing on with the same method I have the following concentrations for $\ce{CO3^2-}$ and $\ce{Ca^2+}$ to be $10^{-5.13}$ and $10^{-3.35}$, respectively. Am I still correct here?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Pure water is in contradiction with ocean mentioned on the title, as sea water contains 1-4 % of sodium chloride. It affects activity coefficients and dissolved calcium and magnesium ions interact with carbonate.

Comment: Thank you @Poutnik, I have changed it now.

Comment: Better than words and numbers is writing  applicable algebraic equations. And, as I have recently written somewhere, eq. (2) considers as H2CO3(aq) both H2CO3(aq) and CO2(aq).Their equilibrium constant and both kinetic rate constants are known.

Comment: @Poutnik , apologies but I do not appear to be able to see this post you mention. Do you mind providing me with the title?

Comment: This one  https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/147451/how-to-calculate-molar-concentration-from-equilibrium-equations-with-no-initial

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to calculate molar concentration from equilibrium equations with no initial concentration given?](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/147451/how-to-calculate-molar-concentration-from-equilibrium-equations-with-no-initial)

Comment: @NisargBhavsar , sorry but it does not. I have updated the question to include why it is different. Thanks,